# Player X and Y position not changing after calling set method

Tags: java, arrays, position, element

I'm making a Board game, and I have to make the player position on the board change based on the dieRoll int that is rolled. But every time the player rolls the dice the position on the board does not change. From some troubleshooting it seems to be the actual players X and Y positions are not changing, rather than the board displaying incorrectly.

My dice roll and move player method

```
public void rollDiceAndMovePlayer(){
    setDice();
    throwField.setText(String.valueOf(getDice()));
    //player1.setPosX(2) to test PosX change, doesn't work.
    player1.setPosX(2);
    if(player1.getPosY() == BOARD_SIZE - 1){
        if(player1.getPosX() < BOARD_SIZE - 1 ){
            player1.setPosX(player1.getPosX()+getDice());
        } else {
            //only accepting winning roll
            if(player1.getPosX() + getDice() == BOARD_SIZE - 1){
                //CHANGE TO JOPTIONPANE ##################################
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(player1.getPosX()+getDice() > BOARD_SIZE -1){
        player1.setPosY(player1.getPosY()+1);
        player1.setPosY(player1.getPosY()+getDice() - BOARD_SIZE);
    }
    else{
        player1.setPosX(player1.getPosX()+getDice());
    }
    display();
```

My player Element class has two static variables

```
private int playerPosX = 0;
private int playerPosY = 0;
```

the set and get methods for X and Y:

```
public void setPosX(int a){
    int playerPosX = a;
}
public int getPosX(){
    return playerPosX;
}
```

I've ensured that the display method for the board does infact remove the old board and reprint it. I had played a JOptionPane in the rollDiceAndMovePlayer method to test the dieRoll and players X and Ys, and it seems the X and Ys stay at 0. I've even had my professor look at my code and he can not find the problem either. I'm inclined to think its an issue with the setPosX/Y methods but can't figure it out.

If anyone has any idea what the problem is its greatly appreciated.

Comment: `int playerPosX = a;` is declared locally to your `setPosX` method, meaning it has no effect on your instance fields, make it `playerPosX = a;` or `this.playerPosX = a;` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting the value of a local variable, not the one you should be. The one you should be setting is the class variable, the instance variable. A local variable is only visible to the code in the function, and nowhere else. Once that function finishes the value of the local is lost. That's the difference between an instance variable and local variable.

```
public void setPosX(int a){
    //int playerPosX = a;   incorrect
    this.playerPosX = a;    correct
}
```